# How do install a python module

Tags: python, ubuntu, bitcoin, python-module

I am a C# developer and have decided to jump into Bitcoin programming using Python in Ubuntu, so I don't know much about python at the moment.

I downloaded [some example code](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/code/key-to-address-ecc-example.py) and at the top it says

`import bitcoin`

It seems I need to somehow setup pybitcointools as a bitcoin module to use with Python based on the book [Mastering Bitcoin 2nd Edition](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/tree/develop/code).

However, I can't seem to figure out how to install pybitcointools.  I know it's not installed because my first example code gives the error:

```
oshirowanen@oshirowanen:~/Desktop$ python3 ./key-to-address-ecc-example.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./key-to-address-ecc-example.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bitcoin
ImportError: No module named 'bitcoin'
```

What have I already tried?

`sudo aptitude install python-pip`

`sudo pip install pybitcointools`

and I get a message saying that it has installed successfully.

Comment: I'm confused.. "I know it's not installed" ... then "I get a message saying that it has installed successfully"

Comment: @DeepSpace Well, he also has some example code that he downloaded from some unspecified place on the internet and isn't showing us, which gives an error which is the empty string, so…

Comment: Its really not worth our time helping you when you can just read the python docs. If we help you with this question you are going to get stuck with another step that you will encounter

Comment: @DeepSpace, Forgot the example error message.  Now added.

Comment: @GabrielFair, I checked some docs and it suggesting installing modules using pip, I tried that method, it didn't work.

Comment: @abarnert, example code link added.

Comment: You installed a package named `bitcointools`, then tried to import a module named `bitcoin`. What makes you think that package supplies that module?

Comment: @abarnert, Based on the book which I linked above, just before the example code, it says pybitcointools is needed.  So naturally, I am led to assume that module is needed.

Comment: Meanwhile, when I look at [`pybitcointools` in PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pybitcointools/), it has an empty description. If I click on the Homepage, it's [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) containing nothing but a README file saying "I really don't have time to maintain this library further. If you want to fork it or use it despite lack of maintenance, feel free to clone locally and revert one commit." So, whatever this package _used_ to provide, it hasn't provided anything since December 2017.

Comment: @abarnert, thats right, hence my question here. because resources are slim regarding that module.  So I was hoping to get help from someone who might have used that module in the past.

Comment: So you're asking how to use a package that no longer exists? The answer to that is easy: either you have to fork it and take over building and maintaining it yourself (which is going to be a major project, and almost certainly not something you want to do as your first foray into Python), or you just can't use it. Which means your book is out of date and useless, which sucks, but there's nothing anyone can do about that.

Comment: @abarnert, the package exists, its just not maintained.  I installed the package using pip.  But the book being out of date sucks indeed, as the book was released only a year ago.  Which I guess some will say is a lifetime in the programming world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you're looking for [has an empty description on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pybitcointools/) and installs nothing when you install it.

If you click on the Homepage link, it's [a GitHub repo](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) containing nothing but a README file saying:

> I really don't have time to maintain this library further. If you want to fork it or use it despite lack of maintenance, feel free to clone locally and revert one commit.

So, whatever this package *used* to provide before December 2017, it no longer does.

Options:

1. Just accept that the book is obsolete and therefore useless. Even if it's only a year old. (Somewhere I still have a book that's mostly about guesses about what's going to be in Java 1.1… nowadays, I don't usually buy books unless they're about ancient-enough-to-be-stable technology.)
2. If you really want to, you can do what that README suggests. But honestly, if you don't know enough about Git to fork the repo and revert the blanking commit, enough about `pip` to install from a Git repo, and enough about Python to update and maintain the code, that's not going to do you any good.
3. You could try searching for other forks of the library on Github, but trying to figure out if one of them is being maintained by someone who knows what they're doing just by looking over the repos is pretty much impossible if you don't know enough about what they're doing.
4. You could try to find some Python Bitcoin programming community mailing list, IRC channel, forum, chat site, whatever and ask people there what they're doing. Stack Overflow is definitely not the right place to ask that. The lists and channels on Python's [Community](https://www.python.org/community/) site might at least be able to point you in the right direction. Or maybe [the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read their help first and see if it's on topic.